# WebDriver takeScreenshot() returns blank screen

Tags: selenium, jenkins, webdriver, cucumber, screenshot

If I try on my local machine (Macbook)

```
byte[] screen = driver.takeScreenshot();
```

Driver:

```
public byte[] takeScreenshot() {
        return ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }
```

I get

> SCREENSHOT BYTES: 
>   -119807871131026100001373726882008520054886000-7418-1053100122110567678073676732801141111021051081010072
>   ...
>   66-51-53-81-71-37-7131115-33-25-66-501218163264-12801248163264-12801248163264-12801248163264-12801291446-13-31-13-36105-1856119-104-112-3112194-3361471279-107-3665110-3364000073697868-826696-126

But if I try it on Jenkins Windows slave, I get

> SCREENSHOT BYTES: 
>   -1198078711310261000013737268820040002-1058600028-82566600109573686584120-100-19-63491000-62-96-11791091063
>   960000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000...00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000466116-201-91-24-43-101000073697868-826696-126

which is image, but blank (invisible).

I tried it in Chromedriver, Geckodriver and IE driver as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I met almost the same problem and resolved it by **updating** my Chrome from version 59.0.3071.115 to **[Google Chrome beta v60.0.3112.40](https://www.google.co.jp/chrome/browser/beta.html)**.

My problem is that Selenium screenshot works good locally but only takes ***blank*** screenshot on Jenkins since last week. This is the [screenshot before my updating to Chrome Beta version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYkUr.png).

Then I found that Google realsed a new version of Chrome on 27th Jun. And my Chrome automatically updated on 30th June.That's all the reason.

I tried upgrating the chromedriver for 2.28 to 2.3, rolling back Chrome to version 64_59.0.3071.86, but it never worked. Then I found links below is really helpful.

※   [Chrome 59 remote desktop chromedriver.exe saves white/blank](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=1844&can=2&start=0&num=100&q=screenshots&colspec=ID%20Status%20Pri%20Owner%20Summary&groupby=&sort=-id)

※   [Selenium ChromeDriver makes blank screenshots](https://serverfault.com/questions/856748/selenium-chromedriver-makes-blank-screenshots)

Comment: Your answer was perfect. I tried Chrome in beta (60.0.3112.50) and it works  well. And it will not be ruined with update. After stable release I will install stable Chrome back.

Answer (score 1):

This happened on a Windows machine for me.  In the Chrome update 59 notes, one of the highlights is:

> Full page screenshots - Take a screenshot of the entire page, from the
>   top of the viewport to the bottom.

I'm assuming that something in that update broke screenshots using Jenkins.  I found that rolling back to the previous version of Chrome fixed the issue for me.  (Look up the build version [here](https://omahaproxy.appspot.com/) then download that version [here](https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-snapshots/index.html)).

I've also submitted a ticket [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=736808) to google for this issue since I couldn't find any others.  Maybe if other people comment on it, it'll get some steam.